# Error APT Updates

Tags: apt, 16.04, ppa, update-manager, repository

when I use `sudo apt-get update` will definitely show a warning like this

```
w: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/xampp/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/xampp/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Why i can fix it? please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Repositories u have added before has no packages...so i do this

```
  sudo apt-get autoclean
```

remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install anything!

Comment: @Deda consider accepting as solution by clicking √ under downvote arrow to mark it green and this solution will be accepted as solved...ty and u r welcome :)

Comment: @Deda glad i could help.